Why does std::vector have 2 constructors instead of 1 with default argument?
I looked at cppreference.com and found this
vector();
explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc );

why not just
explicit vector(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());

1 constructor instead of 2.
Is there a reason for this? same with resize(std::size_t,const T& t) and
resize(std::size_t)
why not just resize(std::size_t,const T& t = T())

The answers for the two functions are actually quite different.  Maybe ask about one at a time?

so i thought about it and for the resize method it is probably to allow a single argument member function pointer to be made while for the constructor I don't know.

Regarding std::vector<T, Allocator>:
For question one, it's a matter of utility and efficiency.
For vector() with no argument:
vector();

The allocator object is supplied by the template, with the default being std::allocator.
The constructor without an argument is a special member, the default constructor.
The definition may be written as:
constexpr vector() : elem(nullptr), array_size(0), space(0) {}

For vector with an allocator object supplied as an argument:
constexpr explicit vector(const Allocator& alloc) noexcept;

The constructor with an allocator object supplied as an argument is not a special member.  The definition may be written as:
constexpr explicit vector(const Allocator& alloc) noexcept : elem(nullptr), array_size(0), space(0), v_alloc(alloc) {}

Both will construct an empty vector.  If "Allocator" is a custom allocator, i.e., "my_allocator", assigning the object via an argument, allows for characteristics that are different from an allocator object supplied by the template.
When the allocator object is supplied by template, all values within the object have default values.  When the allocator object is supplied as an argument, the allocator can be reconfigured before passing the object as an argument.
When vector is constructed without an argument, the allocator is default constructed.  When vector is constructed with an argument, the allocator is first default constructed, then copy assigned from the argument.  Therefore, it would be less efficient to have one constructor with an argument that defaults to "(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())".
For question two, it's a matter of efficiency.
"void resize(std::size_t count)" appends default elements when vector is resized larger.  Each appended element is default constructed via std::allocator_traits:
std::allocator_traits<decltype(v_alloc)>::construct(v_alloc, ptr);

"void resize(std::size_t count, const T& value)" appends elements "value" with a copy constructor when the vector is resized larger.
std::allocator_traits<decltype(v_alloc)>::construct(v_alloc, ptr, value)

If "T()" were supplied as a default for "value", appended elements are copy constructed, rather than default constructed.

If the default constructor were explicit, because it was just the one-argument version with a default, you couldn’t initialize a vector with {}.  For resize, it would require that the element type be copyable rather than just value-initializing (technically value-inserting) the new elements.

explicit vector(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
would require that Allocator is both default constructable and copy-constructable.  If the Allocator is unable to do one of these, then you would be unable to default-construct the vector.

but the allocator requirements require the allocator having a copy constructor anyways

@user24551355 a copy constructor, yes. But not a default constructor

if you dont have a default constructor for allocator you cant even call std::vector default constructor so what is your piont? std::vector default condtructor will call its allocator default constructor too

@user24551355 the Allocator type is a template parameter too, and I'm sure the default has a default constructor.  But you're right, if you used a custom Allocator type it would need a default constructor to use the first form of the constructor.

This is why there's a high-powered C++ committee to figure out the standardeze, this stuff is hard.

@MarkRansom c++ is hard man. There are so many weird decisions.

@MarkRansom the default allocator std::allocator has a default constructor and a copy constructor too but other allocator classes MUST have the copy constructor it is an allocator requirement

To be clear: vector() already requires that Allocator be default-constructible.  Using two constructors instead of one offers no advantage in that regard.
